# Rails 5, refactoring, optimal query for multiple conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails app that I recently updated to Rails 5. I have a data model that looks like this (simplified): `Users` can have many `Apps`, `Users` can also be a `Member` of multiple `Team`s, each `Team` can also have multiple `App`s. In my `App`s index view / controller I want to list all the users apps that he / she have created, I also want to list all the apps that belongs to `Team`s that the `Users` is a `Member` of.

I have a feeling that there is a nicer and more performant way to do it than my current implementation (possibly something new in Rails 5). This is how my current implementation looks:

```
apps = []
# First get all the team apps where the user is a member, but haven't created the app. 
current_or_guest_user.teams.each do |team|
  team.apps.each do |app|
    unless app.user.eql?(current_or_guest_user)
      apps << app
    end
  end
end
# ... then get all the apps that the user have created. 
current_or_guest_user.apps.each do |app|
  unless apps.include?(app)
    apps << app
  end
end
# Return the apps. 
@apps = apps
```

So, is there a cleaner and more optimal way to do what I'm doing? And how does that look?

**Edit**

This is how my active model associations looks like:

```
# App.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :team

# User.rb
has_many :apps, dependent: :destroy
has_many :teams
has_many :teams, through: :members

# Team.rb
has_many :apps, dependent: :destroy
```

**Edit 2**

I wonder if the Rails 5 method `#or` (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052) could be used in this use case, something like:

```
current_user.apps.or([...]])
# [...] = In not exactly sure what to put here in that case.
```

Comment: Would it be ok to paste your model associations in a well formatted manner?

Comment: @oreoluwa I have added the associations now.

Comment: I think a more optimized approach would be to go `Arel`. I don't really think Rails 5 has a better way for this yet. But another way would be to delegate methods, but it may still not be optimized enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following code should accomplish this more concisely:

```
# using a shorter variable name
user = current_or_guest_user

# does the same thing as your first loop over teams
set1 = user.teams.includes(:apps).where("apps.user_id = ?", user.id).map(&:apps)

# does the same thing as the second loop
# (no need to check for duplicates here)
set2 = user.apps

# combine the two queries without adding duplicates
return set1 | set2
```

Apologies if this doesn't work out-the-box, I haven't tested it.

A couple concepts here:

- `includes` will "preload" records through associations. This gets all the associated records through a single query instead of firing individual SQL queries to get each one.
- `where("apps.user_id = ?", user.id)` filters the query based on the user_id of the associated record. The `?` here is a variable that is replaced by `user.id`.

Comment: Thanks, will try it! Do you think it is a possibility to use the new Rails 5 `#or` method in this use case as well or not? https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `or` method. I've been using the [active_record_union](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union) gem

Comment: Would be nice with something like `current_user.apps.or([...])` not exactly sure what to put in `[...]` though. Added it to my original question.

Comment: In this case you'd replace `set1 | set2` with `set1.or(set2)`

Comment: Don't seem to be working exactly how I want it to. This line: `current_user.teams.includes(:apps).where.not(user_id: current_user.id)` returns teams, and not apps in that team. Any ideas on how to get the apps instead?

Comment: I think you need to use `where.not("apps.user_id = ?", current_user.id)`. You're right, I forgot something in my example - added it now. You can just tack on a `.map(&:apps)` at the end

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try it. But what I want is apps in the team that the user is a members of but haven't created the app.